# c how retain data in a modified tree

Tags: c, pointers, struct, tree

So I have a tree that is declared in main and function command to modify it. 
Right now my problem is I scanf in some data and condition 1 runs and it stores the data fine. However when I run condition 2, the tree is overwritten with NULL and the data stored from before is erased. How do I keep the data?

```
typedef struct tree_s tree_t;
typedef struct {
     int i;   
     char a*
}data_t;

struct tree_s {
    data_t data;
    tree_t *left;
    tree_t *right;
};
int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    tree_t *tree = NULL;
    command(input_data, tree);
    return 0;
}

command(blablah){
    if(condition1){
        /*inserts data into tree*/
    if(condition2){
        /*uses data that has been inserted to print something*/
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
void
command(struct_t *c, tree_t **tree) {

switch (*(c->input)) {     /*c->input is a character array*/
    case condition_one:
        process_stock(c, tree);
        break;

    case condition_2:
        process_print_stock(c, tree);
        break;

    default:
        printf("Unrecognised top-level command!.\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: How could we help you if you don't show the relevant parts of your source ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
  {
   tree_t *tree = NULL;
   command(input_data, tree);
   return 0;
  }
```

from what I see in the main function

```
      tree_t *tree = NULL
```

you have initialized "tree" with "NULL" and in the function

```
  command(input_data, tree);
```

you pass its value i.e "NULL" to the "command" function.

replace this with:

```
       command(input_data, &tree);
```

and in the command function define the value of "tree"

Comment: so would i be setting it as tree_t *tree = **tree;?

Comment: if you paste the code of your "command" function I can help you with this

Comment: Edited. Command function is added. Sorry my original code is really long and actually has a lot of different functions so I tried to simplify it down as much as I could so you guys wont have to read like 200 lines. I just need tree to be modified and keep the modifications at the same time so dont worry about the struct_t *c

Comment: ok, call "command" like this: command(input_data, &tree)  but "tree" is still initialized with "NULL"...peraph you did it point to some allocated memory in your "process_stock" or "process_print_stock"??...what the role of "process_stock" and "process_print_stock" also is "struct_t" well defined (typed struct ??)

Comment: Yes tree gets allocated memory in process_stock and print_stock just prints out data that was saved from process_stock . Yea struct_t is properly defined. How would I dereference tree in command

Comment: to allocate "tree" do the following: *tree = (tree_t *)malloc(sizeof(tree_t));   " *tree " is of type " tree_t * " so to access elements in "tree_t" struct, do: (*tree)->data, (*tree)->left, (*tree)->right